# exuberant ctags with C not yielding redirection to function definition properly

Tags: c, vim, exuberant-ctags

I was using ctags with C on an old project, mostly coding in Vim. ctags was working fine[redirecting perfectly]

Now the code base has changed a lot, I ran command : 
`ctags -R`, now when I do `Ctrl + ]`, I am not taken to the function/macro definition as earlier it used to do, at times it takes me to the correct line but mostly it takes me to some lines above/below the actual definition. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Double check you are using Exuberant Ctags, not the original Ctags.

Comment: @ernix I ran `ctags --version`
Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Apr 14 2012, 13:09:28
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex

Comment: Where in your project do you generate that `tags` file?

Comment: @romainl, I have a directory A which contains directories A1, A2, A3, where A1 , A2, A3 contain the source files, I used to run `ctags -R` in direcotry A, which created `tags` file in directory A only

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a tag file for each directory in your project. `ctags -R` only changes the tag file in the current directory It does not change all the tags files recursively. This is why when you do `<C+]>` you jump to a place sort of near the actual definition.

To fix this you should only have one tags file and it should be located at the root of you project. Then in your vimrc add `set tags=./tags;/`. This allows vim to search for a tags file starting from you current directory up the tree until it finds one. (stopping at the root directory)

Comment: directory A is the root of my project, I deleted tags file which were within directory A1, A2. now my project has only one tag file, but still I am redirected to a wrong line in the source

Comment: @MohitAhuja Can you try deleting the tags file in A and rerun `ctags -R`. As for why your jumping to the wrong spot I'm not sure.

Comment: I deleted, and rerun `ctags -R`, still the same problem persists

Comment: I used a work around by checking out the project from repository, below A. Ran `ctags -R`. Now working without worries